# Large RSS feed. How to avoid slowing down the server when retrieved?

Tags: php, apache, rss, feed, zen-cart

I have added an RSS feed on a Zen-cart store, PHP 5.2, apache2. The store has some 25.000 products with their name, description, price, image, etc.

The RSS is stored in a cache to avoid running the query everytime, but even then the server slows down when the RSS is retrieved, sometimes getting a blank page because the max-execution-time is exceeded (I have already set 220 seconds).

Is there any way of better dealing with large RSS feeds? I could always split it in 2 or 3 feeds, but some partners require a single feed url to retrieve all the products in one go.

Comment: I'm curious - why do you have an RSS feed with 25k entries? Who would have to retrieve this on regular basis as people often do with RSS feeds?

Comment: Mainly price comparison sites and the like. But it is not my shop, I don't really know the commercial details I'm afraid.

Comment: If product indexing is the purpose with the feed, I would go with mririgos answer - maybe with a larger span between the generation of the feed. Retrieving a flat file would be a lot faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set a cron to write the RSS feed to the filesystem every 5, 10, .... minutes. This way, the file is already prepared and just needs to be opened instead of processed every time it's hit.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely you going to change the feed through out the day.
So by just cache is not good enough, cache it as static file, update it via crontab daily.

And applied `mod_deflate` like

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
```

Basically, should not add the php layer for serving the RSS request

Comment: Interesting. I have to look this in detail but seems to me like a good posible solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason serving a file out of cache should take any appreciable server time. Something is wrong with your caching. Or maybe you're seeing the timeouts when the cache is stale, in which case you'll need to keep your cache fresh via scheduled refreshes so that clients don't hit a stale cache, ever.

Worst case, cache it out to the filesystem and let Apache serve it as a static page. If you go this route, make sure to write the new version to a temporary and then rename it in to place (you don't want to serve partial content). On POSIX (Unix-like) systems, rename on the same partition to replace a file is atomic.

Comment: I have to admit I haven't checked the caching code yet (is not my code), but it doesn't create a static cache file, it just caches the SQL. I will give a try to creating static cache files via cron. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if you have full control of the webserver, this would be a perfect time to use [MEMCACHE](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)...

Comment: The complete RSS, when downloaded to a file weights around 4Mb I am afraid.

Comment: uhmmm. we have in the neightborhood of 16 GB of memcache data sharded across 6 machines...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be more a memory problem. Even it is not calculated, when you retrieve it from the cache, it is stored in a varibale, and it takes a lot of memory.

Write a static file or increase the memory of your server.

Comment: The server is in a cloud enviroment with auto-scaling, so it shouldn't have memory problems, although I am not sure the auto-scaling feature can deal with memory needs in short intervals.